# Populating nested tables using CAST/MULTISET

Tags: oracle, plsql

Getting error while populating nested collections using CAST/MULTISET.

**Object Creation**

```
--Employee Object 
CREATE TYPE emp_o AS OBJECT (
    employee_id     NUMBER,
    employee_name   VARCHAR2(100),
    salary          NUMBER
);

--Employee table

CREATE TYPE emp_ot IS
    TABLE OF emp_o;
--Department object

CREATE TYPE deps_o AS OBJECT (
    department_id     NUMBER,
    department_name   VARCHAR2(100),
    emp_tab           emp_ot
);
--department table

CREATE TYPE deps_t IS
    TABLE OF deps_o;
```

Below is my query which I am using : Basically trying to populate deps_t table in one go.

```
DECLARE 
  l_message DEPS_T := DEPS_T(); --Initialize 
BEGIN 
  SELECT CAST ( MULTISET (
                SELECT d.department_id, 
                       d.department_name, 
                       CAST(MULTISET(
                              SELECT e.employee_id, 
                                     e.first_name ||' ' ||e.last_name,
                                     e.salary 
                              FROM   hr.employees e 
                              WHERE  e.department_id = d.department_id ) AS EMP_OT) 
                ) AS deps_t)
  INTO   l_message 
  FROM   hr.departments d; 

END;
```

Error I am getting:

```
ORA-06550: line 13, column 17:
PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Comment: The first imbricated `SELECT` has no `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the above code are working as expected however as a developer I found it bit difficult to understand it. 
What about simplifying the above code bit more removing inline queries and `MULTISET` & `CAST` operators?
 See how:

```
DECLARE 
  l_message DEPS_T;
BEGIN 
  SELECT  deps_o(
              d.deptno
             ,d.dname
              --Writing type of table does implicit casting here
             ,EMP_OT(emp_o (
                                    e.empno,
                                    e.ename || ' ' || 'last_name',
                                    e.sal
                                  )                                                                                       
                             ))           
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_message 
  FROM   dept d
  JOIN emp e
  ON e.deptno = d.deptno;      

   for i in 1..l_message.count
   loop
     dbms_output.put_line(l_message(i).department_id ||' '||l_message(i).department_name||' '||l_message(i).emp_tab(1).employee_id);
   end loop;

END;
/
```

Output:

```
SQL> /
10 ACCOUNTING 7782
10 ACCOUNTING 7839
10 ACCOUNTING 7934
20 RESEARCH 7566
20 RESEARCH 7902
20 RESEARCH 7876
20 RESEARCH 7369
20 RESEARCH 7788
30 SALES 7521
30 SALES 7844
30 SALES 7499
30 SALES 7900
30 SALES 7698
30 SALES 7654

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @GMB
Below query works

```
DECLARE 
  l_message DEPS_T := DEPS_T(); --Initialize 
BEGIN 
  SELECT CAST ( MULTISET (
                SELECT d.department_id, 
                       d.department_name, 
                       (CAST(MULTISET(
                              SELECT e.employee_id, 
                                     e.first_name ||' ' ||e.last_name,
                                     e.salary 
                              FROM   hr.employees e 
                              WHERE  e.department_id = d.department_id ) AS EMP_OT) )
                FROM hr.departments d) AS deps_t)
  INTO   l_message 
  FROM DUAL;


END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to initialise the collection and you can get rid of the outer `CAST`/`MULTISET` by using `BULK COLLECT INTO`. You can also explicitly create the `deps_o` and `emp_o` objects (creating `emp_o` is optional as `MULTISET` will handle it but it is required for `deps_o` as `BULK COLLECT INTO` expects a single column to be input for each variable it is collecting into):

```sql
DECLARE 
  l_message DEPS_T;
BEGIN 
  SELECT deps_o(
           department_id,
           department_name,
           CAST(
             MULTISET(
               SELECT emp_o(
                        employee_id,
                        first_name || ' ' || last_name,
                        salary
                      )
               FROM   employees e
               WHERE  e.department_id = d.department_id
             ) AS emp_ot
           )
         )
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_message 
  FROM   departments d; 
END;
/
```